# clear the pictureboximage

Tags: vb.net

how can i clear the image in a picturebox to draw a new image.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have two buttons on the interface to clear the image and redraw image, you can use following functions on their click handlers.

**VB**

```
Private Sub ClearImage()
        PictureBox1.Image = Nothing
    End Sub

    Private Sub SetImage(ByVal img As Image)
        PictureBox1.Image = img
    End Sub
```

**C#**

```
public void ClearImage()
{
 PictureBox1.Image = null;
}

public void SetImage( Image img)
{
 PictureBox1.Image = img;
}
```

Comment: oops.. I provided c# sample..

Answer (score 1):

Create a new Bitmap object with the value of width and height.

```
PictureBox1.Image = New Bitmap(100, 100)
```

Comment: where can i place this code?
on paint or button click?

Answer (score 0):

```
PictureBox1.Image = Nothing
```

Comment: its working.but there have no chance to draw a image without the form load